# VBA syntax in Access 2010: How to open form to specific record with composite primary key

Tags: vba, syntax, ms-access-2010, where-clause

*edited following andshrew's answer*

I'm just finding my feet in VBA scripting and am a bit stumped with this rather simple bit of code. I suspect it is because I'm not getting the syntax of the Where statement right. The code below should open a form to the one record that matches both filter expressions but instead it opens to a blank record. If I only use one filter expression, it works as desired and opens the form to the correct subset of records. From what I found elsewhere it should be possible to combine multiple filter criteria with an AND, so I'm at a loss why this isn't working.

See below the code for a more extensive description of what I'm trying to do, in case this isn't a simple syntax issue after all.

```
Private Sub lsPrevObs_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim Microchip As String
    Dim ObsDate As Date
    Microchip = Me.Text24
    ObsDate = Me.lsPrevObs
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmObservationsEdit", acNormal, , "ObsMicrochip ='" & Microchip & "' AND TrappingDate = #" & ObsDate & "#", acFormEdit
End Sub
```

Context for this sub:

I have a table containing basic information about individual animals with their microchip number (despite the name it does contain letters and is therefore a string, not an integer) as primary key. Then I have a table of observations, which uses the Microchip number and the observation date as a composite primary key.
I have a form linked to the first table. A text box (Text24) displays the microchip number of the current record and a list box (lsPrevObs) shows the dates of observations for the animal for which there already are records in the observation table. I want to tie some VBA code to the double click event of the list box so that when the user double clicks a date, a new form opens (frmObservationsEdit, DataEntry=No) and allows for that observation record to be edited.

Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the code in your example is incorrect, you're currently using the VBA 'and' command rather than sending a SQL 'and' as part of the Where string.

Simply changing your code as follows to make sure the and is within the quotes should make it work.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmObservationsEdit", acNormal, , "ObsMicrochip ='" & Microchip & "' and TrappingDate = #" & ObsDate & "#", acFormEdit
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Making the AND part of the SQL Where string does compile, so you are correct about that, but it then fails to do the job. The form opens at an empty record. When I modify my code to filter by either of the two expressions it works and I get the correct subsets of records in my form, but as soon as I try to combine two expressions with an AND it comes up empty rather than with the one record that matches. It seems the VBA code for filtering on composite criteria is not as straight forward as one would hope.